# Google Chrome Extensions. Удаление обработчиков tabs.onUpload

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Здравствуйте!
Пишу расширение для Chrome.

в manifest.json:

```
...
"background": {
   "scripts": ["background.js"]
}
...
```

в background.js:

```
function addListener(tabMain) {
    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
        if (tabId == tabMain.id && changeInfo.status == "complete") {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, { file: "toExecute.js" }, function () {});
        }
    });
}
```

Добавляю обработчики специально в background, чтобы после закрытия popup окна расширения обработчик продолжал работу.

AddListener вызываю в popup.js при нажатии на кнопку в popup.html;

Теперь вопрос, каким образом можно остановить/удалить данный обработчик события chrome.tabs.onUpdated?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно в метод `chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener` передавать не анонимную, а именованную функцию. А для удаления обработчика вызвать метод `chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener`.

Напр. так:

```
// tabMain или сразу tabMainId нужно сделать глобальной переменной
var tabMain = XXX;

function onUpdated(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  if (tabId == tabMain.id && changeInfo.status == "complete") {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, { file: "toExecute.js" }, function () {});
  }
}

// добавить обработчик
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(onUpdated);

// убрать обработчик
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(onUpdated);
```